# Can I attach Selenium to an existing IE browser session with Java?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer

I know this question has been asked in some variants before, but I haven't found a way to solve the problem yet.
I would like to attach with Selenium to an existing browser session in Internet Explorer, using Java.
I have seen a way for this in Chrome, but we have a tool that uses an embedded IE, and now I would like to connect to that.

I have tried things like:

- IEDriverServer /port=1234

Then starting an IE session with

- http://127.0.0.1:1234/

and connection to it by:

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:1234/");

WebDriver driver2 = new RemoteWebDriver(url,capabilities);

but this gives me the exception:

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: only one session may be created at a time, and a session already exists

If you know a workaround for this, I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance!